# CSS clipped image inside static container positioned absolute to grandparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I have multiple image tiles that should show a full image in the end. In my code below you can hopefully get an idea of what I want to achieve. I have a grandparent div which will be hidden by always a left and a right image. For now I wrapped the images with a parent container div ("parent") to set the size for the tiles. My problem is now that the "overflow: hidden" only works if I set the parent to "position: relative". But in order to position the images absolutely to the grandparent, the relative positioning of the parent interferes with my plans. Have you any ideas how I can achieve this? If this isn't possible in CSS, I could also use JS for it.

```css
.grandparent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 125px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="child left" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/25/13/01/stones-167089_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="child right" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/25/13/01/stones-167089_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `overflow:hidden` but consider `clip-path` instead. It will do the same as overflow and you are not required to consider `position:relative`

```css
.grandparent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 125px;
  clip-path:inset(0); /* this will hide the overflow */
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="child left" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/25/13/01/stones-167089_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="child right" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/25/13/01/stones-167089_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```